# VBA: Error in code for Matrix Multiplication

Tags: vba

I am trying to write a general code for matrix multiplication but when I am trying to verify it, the output is always a null matrix. So it seems that the values of the temp matrix are not getting updated.

Please suggest some changes for it to work. The code is copied below:

```
Public Function matrixmultiply(x() As Double, y() As Double) As Double()

Dim nrow1 As Integer, nrow2 As Integer, ncol1 As Integer, ncol2 As Integer, i As   Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, temp() As Double

nrow1 = UBound(x, 1) - LBound(x, 1) + 1
ncol1 = UBound(x, 2) - LBound(x, 2) + 1

nrow2 = UBound(y, 1) - LBound(y, 1) + 1
ncol2 = UBound(y, 2) - LBound(y, 2) + 1

ReDim matrixmultiply(1 To nrow1, 1 To ncol2)
ReDim temp(1 To nrow1, 1 To ncol2)

For i = 1 To nrow1
    For j = 1 To ncol2
    d = 2
        For k = 1 To col1
            temp(i, j) = temp(i, j) + x(i, k) * y(k, j)
        Next k
    Next j
Next i

matrixmultiply = temp

End Function


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim x(1 To 3, 1 To 3) As Double, y(1 To 3, 1 To 3) As Double, z() As Double
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

For i = 1 To 3
    For j = 1 To 3
        x(i, j) = Cells(i, j).Value
        y(i, j) = Cells(i, j + 5).Value
    Next j
Next i

z = matrixmultiply(x, y)

For i = 1 To 3
    For j = 1 To 3
        Cells(i, j + 12).Value = z(i, j)
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` in the beginning of the module.

Comment: why don't you put your matrices in ranges and use MMULT() ? It might be simpler and faster.

Comment: Hi Gserg, your suggestion really helped. I had mistyped one of the variables.

Comment: @iDevlop, I am actually trying to develop a general algorithm which can be handle large matrices as well since MMULT() has limits to the size of the matrix.

Comment: Side note: There are some more matrix-friendly languages that interface with VBA.  Take a look into R, perhaps.

Comment: I would have loved to but this code is a part of a project that I need to build around MS Excel and hence I have to use VBA and nothing else. :)

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake in the line:

```
For k = 1 To col1
```

It should, instead, be

```
For k = 1 To ncol1
```

Using `Option Explicit` would have saved a lot of hurt!

Comment: Hi @hnk, that still is a correct answer. Thanks for your effort and concern :)